# Automatically create sequential stages in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure Pipeline `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
parameters:
  - name: "stages"
    type: object
    default:
    - stage1
    - stage2
    # possibly more...

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: InitialStage
    displayName: I must run first
    jobs: ...

  - ${{ each stage in parameters.stages }}:
    - stage:
      dependsOn: InitialStage
      condition: succeeded()
      jobs: ...
```

What I want to achieve is creating a pipeline where the first stage is `InitialStage`, then I want to generate the next stages to run after it sequentially. So the final pipeline should look like:

```
InitialStage ==> stage1 ==> stage2 ==> ...
```

One stage must run after the previous completed and the first stage in absolute must be `InitialStage`.

If I use the syntax above, I get the stages run in parallel like:

```
InitialStage ==> stage1
             |
             ==> stage2
             |
             ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the `dependsOn` keyword. [Per Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#specify-dependencies):

> When you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run sequentially in the order in which you define them in the YAML file. The exception to this is when you add dependencies. With dependencies, stages run in the order of the dependsOn requirements.

Can also remove the `condition` keyword:

> You can specify the conditions under which each stage runs. By default, a stage runs if it does not depend on any other stage, or if all of the stages that it depends on have completed and succeeded. You can customize this behavior by forcing a stage to run even if a previous stage fails or by specifying a custom condition.

If you do need to map custom stage dependencies, I have done this before as well by creating a stage object. Something like:

```
parameters:
- name: environmentObjects
  type: object
  default:
  - environmentName: 'dev'
    dependsOn: ''
  - environmentName: 'tst'
    dependsOn: 'dev'
```

and then looped through and dynamically build the dependsOn. This would allow for scenarios with two test environmnts depending on dev but not each other.